# Magento - Override order controller

Tags: php, magento, controllers

I want to override the following controller which creates orders in the backend:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php
```

I have copied the file itself into:

```
app/code/community/Pinto/PartnerSystem/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php
```

For the sake of not being sure where or how exactly to copy the file/directory structure I also copied it into:

```
app/code/community/Pinto/PartnerSystem/controllers/AdminControllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php
```

I then renamed the class to:

```
class PartnerSystem_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController 
{ 
// functions 
}
```

In my **config.xml** I have added the following:

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <partnersystem>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Pinto_PartnerSystem_AdminControllers</module>
                    <frontName>partnersystemadmin</frontName>
                </args>
            </partnersystem>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <partnersystem before="Mage_Adminhtml">PartnerSystem_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController</partnersystem>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>  
    </admin>
```

I'm not quite sure as to what I should put between the  to make it use my `CreateController.php` instead of the base one.

Quite new to Magento so could use some help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct path of your new controller is :
`app/code/community/Pinto/PartnerSystem/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/CreateController.php` (switch the folders `controllers` and `Adminhtml`).
This line from config:

```
<partnersystem before="Mage_Adminhtml">PartnerSystem_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController</partnersystem>
```

should be

```
<partnersystem before="Mage_Adminhtml">Pinto_PartnerSystem_Adminhtml</partnersystem>
```

and in your new controller file, before the class definitions add this

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php'
```

**[EDIT]**
The new controller class name should be `Pinto_PartnerSystem_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController`.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for the quick reply! It seems to recognize the new controller file now - however I included the original class before the class definition as you said and I get the following error: 'Controller file was loaded but class does not exist'.

Comment: @DanielPaul. Oh yeah...I forgot an other thing. The new controller class name should be `Pinto_PartnerSystem_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController`. I will add it to the answer

Comment: Ah, forgot the namespace! Thank you it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little notification on the include path of the controller.

This include path **can cause errors** if the **Magento Compiler mode** is turned on.

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php';
```

Instead of that it is **good to use**

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales_Order_CreateController.php';
```

It will be safer.
Hope this helps..

Comment: I have used this modified code :  require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Sales'.DS.'Order'.DS.'CreateController.php';